# How to split a pandas string to extract middle names?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, split

I want to split names of individuals into multiple strings. I am able to extract the first name and last name quite easily, but I have problems extracting the middle name or names as these are quite different in each scenario.

The data would look like this:

```
ID| Complete_Name               | Type
1 | JERRY, Ben                  | "I"
2 | VON HELSINKI, Olga          | "I"
3 | JENSEN, James Goodboy Dean  | "I"
4 | THE COMPANY                 | "C"
5 | CRUZ, Juan S. de la         | "I"
```

Whereby there are names with only a first and last name and names with something in between or two middle names. How can I extract the middle names from a Pandas dataframe? I can already extract the first and last names.

```
df = pd.read_csv("list.pip", sep="|")
df["First Name"] = 
np.where(df["Type"]=="I",df['Complete_Name'].str.split(',').str.get(1) , df[""])
df["Last Name"] = np.where(df["Type"]=="I",df['Complete_Name'].str.split(' ').str.get(1) , df[""])
```

The desired results should look like this:

```
ID| Complete_Name               | Type | First Name | Middle Name | Last Name
1 | JERRY, Ben                  | "I"  | Ben        |             | JERRY
2 | VON HELSINKI, Olga          | "I"  | Olga       |             |
3 | JENSEN, James Goodboy Dean  | "I"  | James      | Goodboy Dean| VON HELSINKI
4 | THE COMPANY                 | "C"  |            |             |
5 | CRUZ, Juan S. de la         | "I"  | Juan       | S. de la    | CRUZ
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splitting a column by delimiter pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-column-by-delimiter-pandas-python)

Comment: ^ Nope, not that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single `str.extract` call will work here:

```
p = r'^(?P<Last_Name>.*), (?P<First_Name>\S+)\b\s*(?P<Middle_Name>.*)' 
u = df.loc[df.Type == "I", 'Complete_Name'].str.extract(p)
pd.concat([df, u], axis=1).fillna('')

   ID               Complete_Name Type     Last_Name First_Name   Middle_Name
0   1                  JERRY, Ben    I         JERRY        Ben              
1   2          VON HELSINKI, Olga    I  VON HELSINKI       Olga              
2   3  JENSEN, James Goodboy Dean    I        JENSEN      James  Goodboy Dean
3   4                 THE COMPANY    C                                       
4   5         CRUZ, Juan S. de la    I          CRUZ       Juan      S. de la
```

**Regex Breakdown**

```
^                # Start-of-line
(?P<Last_Name>   # First named capture group - Last Name
    .*           # Match anything until...
)
,                # ...we see a comma
\s               # whitespace 
(?P<First_Name>  # Second capture group - First Name
    \S+          # Match all non-whitespace characters
)
\b               # Word boundary 
\s*              # Optional whitespace chars (mostly housekeeping) 
(?P<Middle_Name> # Third capture group - Zero of more middle names 
    .*           # Match everything till the end of string
)
```

Comment: Pretty neat, but can you explain the regex in more detail for people who will visit in the future so that they can adapt the regex to their own needs?

Comment: @mrPy Edited, hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do:

```
# take the complete_name column and split it multiple times
df2 = (df.loc[df['Type'].eq('I'),'Complete_Name'].str
       .split(',', expand=True)
       .fillna(''))

# remove extra spaces 
for x in df2.columns:
    df2[x] = [x.strip() for x in df2[x]]

# split the name on first space and join it
df2 = pd.concat([df2[0],df2[1].str.split(' ',1, expand=True)], axis=1)
df2.columns = ['last','first','middle']

# join the data frames
df = pd.concat([df[['ID','Complete_Name']], df2], axis=1)

# rearrange columns - not necessary though
df = df[['ID','Complete_Name','first','middle','last']]

# remove none values
df = df.replace([None], '')

   ID                  Complete_Name Type  first        middle          last
0   1   JERRY, Ben                      I    Ben                       JERRY
1   2   VON HELSINKI, Olga              I   Olga                VON HELSINKI
2   3   JENSEN, James Goodboy Dean      I  James  Goodboy Dean        JENSEN
3   4   THE COMPANY                     C                                   
4   5   CRUZ, Juan S. de la             I   Juan      S. de la          CRUZ
```

Comment: Seems to work YOLO, except for the fact that you did not take into account the np.where(df.Type=="I"). So it also splits the "C" types.

Comment: @mrPy sorry i missed that part, fixing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer that uses some simple lambda functionality.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


""" Create data and data frame """

info_dict = {
    'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,],
    'Complete_Name':[
        'JERRY, Ben',
        'VON HELSINKI, Olga',
        'JENSEN, James Goodboy Dean',
        'THE COMPANY',
        'CRUZ, Juan S. de la',
        ],
    'Type':['I','I','I','C','I',],
    }

data = pd.DataFrame(info_dict, columns = info_dict.keys())


""" List of columns to add """
name_cols = [
    'First Name',
    'Middle Name',
    'Last Name',
    ]

"""
Use partition() to separate first and middle names into Pandas series.
Note: data[data['Type'] == 'I']['Complete_Name'] will allow us to target only the
values that we want.
"""
NO_LAST_NAMES = data[data['Type'] == 'I']['Complete_Name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).partition(',')[2].strip())
LAST_NAMES = data[data['Type'] == 'I']['Complete_Name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).partition(',')[0].strip())

# We can use index positions to quickly add columns to the dataframe.
# The partition() function will keep the delimited value in the 1 index, so we'll use
# the 0 and 2 index positions for first and middle names.
data[name_cols[0]] = NO_LAST_NAMES.str.partition(' ')[0]
data[name_cols[1]] = NO_LAST_NAMES.str.partition(' ')[2]

# Finally, we'll add our Last Names column
data[name_cols[2]] = LAST_NAMES

# Optional: We can replace all blank values with numpy.NaN values using regular expressions.
data = data.replace(r'^$', np.NaN, regex=True)
```

Then you should end up with something like this:

```
   ID               Complete_Name Type First Name   Middle Name     Last Name
0   1                  JERRY, Ben    I        Ben           NaN         JERRY
1   2          VON HELSINKI, Olga    I       Olga           NaN  VON HELSINKI
2   3  JENSEN, James Goodboy Dean    I      James  Goodboy Dean        JENSEN
3   4                 THE COMPANY    C        NaN           NaN           NaN
4   5         CRUZ, Juan S. de la    I       Juan      S. de la          CRUZ
```

Or, replace NaN values with with blank strings:

```
data = data.replace(np.NaN, r'', regex=False)
```

Then you have:

```
   ID               Complete_Name Type First Name   Middle Name     Last Name
0   1                  JERRY, Ben    I        Ben                       JERRY
1   2          VON HELSINKI, Olga    I       Olga                VON HELSINKI
2   3  JENSEN, James Goodboy Dean    I      James  Goodboy Dean        JENSEN
3   4                 THE COMPANY    C                                       
4   5         CRUZ, Juan S. de la    I       Juan      S. de la          CRUZ
```