# Pandas split each row by delimiter into two columns (5GB CSV)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Relatively new and trying to split some data with python from a CSV file.
My data is structured as follows:

```
Time| Signature
--------------------
0   | Class1#Method1
1   | Class4#Method5
2   | Class5# <--note that Class 5 has no method
```

What I try to accomplish is to manipulate the data set such that it becomes

```
Time| Class  | Method
--------------------
0   | Class1 | Method1
1   | Class4 | Method5
```

Class 5 is removed in the splitting process since it has no method.

I've tried to iterate over the whole dataset - works, but it is VERY slow when dealing with a 5gb csv file. Does anyone have a faster approach? Speed is everything that counts

Comment: We'll need a bit more explanation : Are you using Pandas to deal with your csv rows ? Is your Signature attribute a string like "Class1#Method1" that you first have to separate, or is the separation already done by another way ?

Comment: Yes, I use a pandas dataframe to deal with the data. My signature attribute is a string like "Class1#Method1". What I try to accomplish is to split Class1#Method1 into Class1 and Method1 (so delimiter is #)  and discarding signatures with no method @BeamsAdept

Comment: Does this answer your question? [splitting a column by delimiter pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-column-by-delimiter-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use something like `df[['Class','Method']] = df['Signature'].str.split('#',expand=True)`

(from [splitting a column by delimiter pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-column-by-delimiter-pandas-python))