# Pandas: How to split on multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've dataframe which contains latitude, longitude and altitude in single column (`coordinates`) and I want to split `coordinates` column into three columns(latitude, longitude and altitude).

df:

```
ID                                                         Coordinates                                                      Region  
1     latitude_degrees: 52.00755721100514\nlongitude_degrees: 12.565129548994266\naltitude_meters: 185.23616827199143\n     Europe   
2     latitude_degrees: 52.00755721100514\nlongitude_degrees: 12.565129548994266\naltitude_meters: 185.23616827199143\n     Europe   
3     latitude_degrees: 52.00755721100514\nlongitude_degrees: 12.565129548994266\naltitude_meters: 185.23616827199143\n     Europe   
4     latitude_degrees: 52.00755721100514\nlongitude_degrees: 12.565129548994266\naltitude_meters: 185.23616827199143\n     Europe   
5     latitude_degrees: 52.00755721100514\nlongitude_degrees: 12.565129548994266\naltitude_meters: 185.23616827199143\n     Europe
```

Expected Output:

```
ID           lat                lon                     alt             Region  
1      52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266     185.23616827199143     Europe   
2      52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266     185.23616827199143     Europe   
3      52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266     185.23616827199143     Europe   
4      52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266     185.23616827199143     Europe   
5      52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266     185.23616827199143     Europe
```

What I tried:

I tried to first split columns on `:` basis but it's not working:

```
df.loc[df['Coordinates'].isin(["latitude_degrees", "longitude_degrees"])]= ""
```

I also tried to replace the text but it's not working:

```
df.Coordinates.replace(to_replace=['latitude_degrees','longitude_degrees'],value='')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-column-by-delimiter-pandas-python

Comment: @YukiShioriii Thanks, but I've already tried this one and it's not working

Comment: What have you tried ? the answer which use `str.split` is not in your provided code.

Comment: @YukiShioriii I've tried 100 of answers but cannot add everything in question, right?

Comment: add the str.split one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract `lat`, `long` and `alt` from the `Coordinates` column, then `unstack` it to reshape, finally `join` this with the columns `ID` and `Region`:

```
c = df['Coordinates'].str.extractall(r'([\d.]+)')[0].unstack()
d = df[['ID', 'Region']].join(c.set_axis(['lat', 'long', 'alt'], 1))
```

---

```
   ID  Region                lat                long                 alt
0   1  Europe  52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266  185.23616827199143
1   2  Europe  52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266  185.23616827199143
2   3  Europe  52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266  185.23616827199143
3   4  Europe  52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266  185.23616827199143
4   5  Europe  52.00755721100514  12.565129548994266  185.23616827199143
```