# Python: How to find correlation of 2 columns having list of values?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have a dataframe like

```
    title                                               titlenew
0   Two Workers Are Struck By Motor Vehicle And O...    two workers are struck by motor vehicle and o...
1   Foreman Is Fatally Crushed When Forklift Tips...    foreman is fatally crushed when forklift tips...
2   Employee Suffers Abdominal Fracture In Fall F...    employee suffers abdominal fracture in fall f...
3   Employee'S Body Is Caught In Asphalt Machine ...    employee's body is caught in asphalt machine ...
4   Employee Is Punctured In Abdomen With Nail  employee is punctured in abdomen with nail
```

that I converted to vectors for NLP processing. They now look like

```
    card2vec_title                                      card2vec_titlenew
0   [0.09446411579847336, 0.18325935304164886, 0.1...   [0.01013200543820858, -0.015507892705500126, 0...
1   [0.11135150492191315, 0.16989260911941528, 0.1...   [0.0871051624417305, 0.07891112565994263, -0.0...
2   [-0.019224125891923904, 0.3285079598426819, -0...   [0.052899472415447235, 0.2530696988105774, -0....
3   [0.06179530546069145, 0.10462947934865952, 0.0...   [0.05848287418484688, 0.062050893902778625, -0...
4   [0.0604548417031765, 0.2742682993412018, -0.00...   [0.09018705040216446, 0.23053207993507385, -0.
```

My question is, how can I find the correlation score (or cosine similarity) of these 2 columns. Doing `df.card2vec_titlenew.corr(df.card2vec_title)` gives an error saying

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

My question is on correlation hence not providing the code for how I converted the strings to vectors. Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: is there any help here?

Comment: show your code.   you should be able run corr from the dataframe, sns.heatmap(weights_df.corr(), center=0, cmap=cmap, linewidths=1,
annot=True, fmt=".2f") and send it to a heatmap.   mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))  sns.heatmap(corr,  cmap=cmap, center=0, linewidths=1, annot=True, fmt=".2f",mask=mask)

Answer (score 0):

Correlation is a one to one, or many to one function, hence the error of list and int, as it expects one int value and not list of values.

Things you could do:

- Do a dot product of the multiple values in each row and then find the correlation between two columns
- Another way would be to split the column for each value(Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-pandas-dataframe-column-by-delimiter)) and then find the correlation between the new columns. However this could be tricky if your columns have different length of words.