# Slice a series of strings by semi colons

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Series` of strings in which the format is `date;value;value`.

I can't use a basic

```
data.str.slice(stop=7)
```

as the values can vary in length.

---

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to slice these stings into 3 columns?

Example:

```
2008-01;12.759358;6.297382

2008-06;17.44426;8.890847
```

Thanks!

Comment: `data.str.split(';', expand=True)`? Answers here are probably helpful [Splitting a pandas dataframe column by delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37333299/15497888)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
"string0;string1;string2".split(';')
```

Further reading:
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html

Comment: This question asks how to split a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) into multiple columns. Not how to split a single python string into a list. This does not answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
raw_string = 2008-01;12.759358;6.297382
formatted = raw_string.split(';')
```