# how to split text in dataframe and put each word in dataframe row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe [image: dataframe]

and I wish to put each word in the `most_used_words_tweet` column in a separate row and it will have the same value in the `hate` column

example: "desired output (2nd row is split to two rows)"

```
     |hate | most_used_words_tweet |
0    |0    |                   اليهود |
1    |0    |                   اليهود |
2    |0    |                     الله |
3    |1    |                   اليهود |
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-pandas-dataframe-column-by-delimiter  splits into colums ... lets see if I find one that does rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows/52973916#52973916](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows/52973916#52973916)

Comment: The split word order is from right to left ?  I seen the order of the 2nd row words presented in reverse order

Comment: @SeaBean Arabic text goes from right to left, but the order doesn't matter

Comment: If you require the words presented in order from right to left, this may be a reason not to mark this question as duplicate.