# Python - How to split a Pandas value and only get the value between the slashs

Tags: python, pandas

Example:
I the `df['column']` has a bunch of values similar to: **F/4500/O** or **G/2/P**

The length of the digits range from 1 to 4 similar to the examples given above.

How can I transform that column to only keep **1449** as an integer?

I tried the split method but I can't get it right.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a pandas dataframe column by delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-pandas-dataframe-column-by-delimiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the value and convert [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'].str.extract('/(\d+)/', expand=False))
```

Example:

```
     column  number
0  F/4500/O    4500
1     G/2/P       2
```

Comment: Hmm...what if some of the OP's data (not shown) happens to have more than one numeric value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not what is suggested in the question, but this would extract the first one, if all needed, then `extractall` + eventually aggregation (but it's a different question)

Comment: Actually, just using `(\d+)` as regex should be sufficient **if** the format is always `non-digits/digits/non-digits`

Answer (score 0):

How's about:

```
df['column'].map(lambda x: int(x.split('/')[1]))
```

Comment: I get the 'list out of index' error. I do have some values with only 2 digits if that matter. I also added str() to x: map(lambda x: int(str(x).split('/')[1])). I'll edit my post about the range of the digits.