# How can I separate column by deliminator and make new columns from the split strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the dataset I'm currently trying to work with:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is separate all the 'genres' values by the comma, and then create new columns called 'genres_Comedy', 'genres_Drama', 'genres_Family' etc where each row will have the value of 0 or 1 depending on if it is that genre. I'm fairly certain it's possible, I know how to separate columns by deliminator, but I don't know how to generate the necessary columns based on the split strings, or how I would then add each rows correct value (0 or 1) with the newly generated columns.

I've tried to look for solutions, but my problem is a bit specific and I can't find any applicable solutions, though maybe I'm looking wrong. Does anyone know how I can go about accomplishing this? Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide that could be helpful, thanks for reading.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you can provided a sample dataframe in your question instead of just an image of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a pandas dataframe column by delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-pandas-dataframe-column-by-delimiter)

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately, I had checked that one out before even, but it only does a part of what I needed. Alan's answer below answers it though and the problem is now solved. Thank you for checking and helping though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is very doable, but takes a couple steps.

**Step 1**

First of all, convert your string column into list of strings. `df["genres"] = df.genres.apply(lambda x: x.split(","), axis=1)`.
(Note, if it's possible that `genres` ends with a `,` then you'll need to remove that or end up with `""` empty string for a genre)

Now the general strategy is to make a new dataframe out of it this list column (with same number of rows, and with columns like `Genre_Comedy` etc), and concat that back on to the original.

**Step 2**

Next: create the new frame from the `genres` column via `genres = df.genres.apply(pd.Series).stack()`. The `apply(pd.Series)` converts the `list` into `pd.Series`, and then `stack()` breaks that into a multi-index Series.

**Step 3**

Next we use `get_dummies`; this is the usual way of creating multiple columns out of one column. If your column is `animal` and one row has `cat` and another has `dog`, then you'll end up with two new columns; one called `animal_cat` and the other `animal_dog`. Same thing here, except now we are working on a multi-index Series. Use it like this: `genres = pd.get_dummies(genres)`. Now you'll have a multi-index dataframe with all your genre columns (Horror, Comedy, etc). Finally just collapse the multi-index via `genres = genres.sum(level=0)`.

**Step 4**

Finally concat it back on via `df = df.concat(genres, axis=1)`

Done!

*I highly recommend printing the output after each line of code to see how the shape of your data evolves. Very hard to understand without visualising it.*

Comment: There is a method `Series.str.get_dummies` which should be able to do steps one to three at once.

Comment: Thank you! This works, though I did have to drop the ````, axis =1```` from step 1, as it was returning: ````TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'```` and also reformat Step 4 to ````testing_df = pd.concat([testing_df, genres], axis=1)```` as it was otherwise returning: ````AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'````. But really thank you, I understand the process a lot better now. Also thank you Michael, that's good to know and I'm looking into it now.