# split array into x y coordinates and plot a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have dataset that looks like below.

[image]

| category | Plot_val | Line1_val | Line2_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat1 | [[1,1.5, 2, 2, 3, 3.5, 4], [12, 15, 20, 25, 20, 30, 40]] | [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]] | [[1, 2, 3, 4], [20, 30, 40, 50]] |

Each val column has array of x and y. I need to create the graph using matplotlib.
Plot_Val should create scatter plot and Line1_val and Line2_val should create lines in same chart. It should looks something like this.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post data as text, not as image. Please add your best-effort reproducible code attempt.  Did you look into post such as [Splitting a pandas dataframe column by delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-pandas-dataframe-column-by-delimiter)?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need, dont really understand the table system you have but if you can get those into variables you can split then and plot then as i have shown below. please NOTE* The data you have is not of equal length so i have chopped off some of the data in plot val x i assume to make this plottable. make sure you have equal number of x and y values otherwise you will not be able to plot them.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

title = "all_plotted"
fig = plt.figure(title)
plt.clf()
rows = 1
cols = 1
grid = plt.GridSpec(
    rows,
    cols
)

ax0 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])

plot_val = [[1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3], [12, 15, 20, 25, 20, 30, 40]]

line1_val = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]

line2_val = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [20, 30, 40, 50]]


plot_val_xs = plot_val[0]
plot_val_ys = plot_val[1]

line1_val_xs = line1_val[0]
line1_val_ys = line1_val[1]

line2_val_xs = line2_val[0]
line2_val_ys = line2_val[1]

ax0.scatter(plot_val_xs, plot_val_ys, color="C0", label="plot_val")
ax0.plot(line1_val_xs, line1_val_ys, color="C1", label="line1")
ax0.plot(line2_val_xs, line2_val_ys, color="C2", label="line2")


ax0.set_xlabel("x axis name")
ax0.set_ylabel("y axis name")
ax0.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

[image: Link to output]